# Creating and Consuming WCF using MVC3

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, c#-4.0

I have a MVC3 project which is empty. I have not added controllers or any views. The only thing I added in MVC project is **Model->Employee.cs**

I have these properties in this class:

```
    [Display(Description="The admin systems group number")]
    public string GroupNumber { get; set; }


    [Display(Description = "The Tax ID for the group (No Dashes)")]
    public string  TaxId { get; set; }
```

Now  I want to add a record of this Employee through WCF service. I created another project inside the same solution named: EmployeeHost

These are my ServiceContract and DataContract in **IService1.cs**:

```
    namespace EmployeeHost
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(int value);

        [OperationContract]
        Employee AddEmployee(Employee emp);

        [OperationContract]
        Employee UpdateEmployee(Employee emp);
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Employee
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string GroupNumber { get; set; }


        [DataMember]
        public string TaxId { get; set; }


    }
}
```

And this is what I have in my Interface: **Service1.cs**

```
 namespace EmployeeHost
{
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }

       public void AddEmployee(Employee emp)
        {
           //Add something to DB for emp.
        }

        public void UpdateEmployee (Employee emp)
       {
            //Update something for employee emp.
       }
    }
}
```

This is what I have so far. Now I want to add a record using DBContext (EF). What should be my next process?

Comment: Just a thought, but will the WCF layer and the MVC application be deployed in the same production server? Because if they will, you don't need to use both WCF and MVC: just a) create a standard model/business/repository class, that will handle the EF calls, and so avoiding creating a WCF service, or b) use WCF REST and JSON, and call the WCF directly from the client, through javascript code.

Comment: It a requirement for me to add through WCF.

Answer (score 1):

The simpler way would be this:

WCF:

1. Make `AddEmployee` call whatever EF code is needed to insert a `EmployeeHost.Employee`.

MVC:

1. Create a view for showing the form page.
2. Add an action on your controller for displaying the view.
3. Add an action on your controller for processing the posted data from the view.
4. Make this last action call the WCF, by first transforming `Model.Employee` into `EmployeeHost.Employee`.

Again, as I have said in my comment, that doesn't make much sense IMHO - unless the WCF is a remote service, deployed in a distinct server from the web application.

Comment: I cannot add in my Service like this: public class Service1 : IService1, DbContext

Comment: @Raj create a distinct class for the DbContext, the WCF service should not be used like that... Sorry, I'll try to find more information about EF, I thought you already knew how to deal with that. :)

Comment: Have you taken a look at [ScottGu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx)? What you're trying to the is basically a code-first EF approach with MVC. Just remember that you have one layer more: instead of making the controller action call the EF entity, make it call the WCF, and the WCF call the EF entity...